# g++ can‘t find stdint.h Windows

Tags: c++, g++, stdint

I have a program that uses the header stb_image.h ini which the stdint.h header is included. The program works completely fine when compiling it in my IDE (Clion). It is now finished however and I would like to have an .exe file of it. So I tried compiling it with g++ by the command:

```
g++ -o imagetotext main.cpp
```

It then however gave me the error:

```
stb_image.h:614: stdint.h: No such file or directory
```

What can I do that g++ finds the stdint.h header? I am using Windows.

Comment: Strange, g++ should find its system headers on its own. Check the compilation logs, CLion should report how it calls g++ itself; if not, peek into project settings, somewhere you should find settings to configure how CLion does. In any case you should be able to compile the executable from within CLion as well, you shouldn't *need* to call g++ directly (if you *want* to, that's another matter...).

Comment: `<stdint.h>` is anyway deprecated in c++, and you should use `<cstdint>` instead. That doesn't explain why it works in CLion, of course.